# JAX-RPC Web services

Tags: web-services

I am new to Apache Axis. Can someone suggest a tutorial for getting started with Apache Axis 1.1/2.0?

Answer (score 2):

http://people.apache.org/~ruchithf/hw-axis2/

http://www.exforsys.com/tutorials/axis2.html

http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/BottomUpAxis2WebService/bu_tutorial.html

http://blogs.deepal.org/2009/06/axis2-tutorials-and-articles.html

are some